# Show $f(x)={x\over x+1}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Show $$f(x)={x\over x+1}$$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$. 
The hints say that **it should be easy to see it is lipschitz** because the derivative is bounded. I tried and tried and I just can't show it. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: without any restriction of the domain the function is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. However, on $[0,\infty)$ is uniformly continuous. This can be  seen with the MVT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using the MVT:
$$|f(x)-f(y)| = |f'(\xi)| |x-y| $$ for some $\xi \in (x,y)$ under the assumption $x<y$ (otherwise $\xi\in(y,x)$). How can you bound $f'(\xi)$? Of course we need to use $x,y\in [0,\infty)$

Comment: Is that a result of Lagrange?

Comment: I was literally just typing the same answer, but you beat me to it haha!

Comment: Didn't know that the MVT is due to Lagrange, but wikipedia says it is. @ Smiley Sam: Sorry :p

Comment: It should take place in a closed interval I believe, doesn't it?

Comment: What should take place in a closed interval?

Comment: Lagrange Mean Value Theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: $x$ and $y$ form the closed interval ... The trick is, that $f'(\xi)$ can be estimated independently of $x$ and $y$ on $[0,\infty)$. How?

Answer (score 3):

An approach is just to write, **on** $[0,\infty)$:
$$
|f(a)-f(b)|=\left| \frac{a}{a+1}- \frac{b}{b+1}\right|=\left| \frac{a(b+1)-b(a+1)}{(a+1)(b+1)}\right|=\left| \frac{a-b}{(a+1)(b+1)}\right|\leq|a-b|
$$ and the function is **lipschitzian**.

Comment: Personally, I would always prefer this answer over mine, since it is so more beautiful and elementary.